# How to replace outliers based on seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

Hi I have a data frame contains 'year', 'month','day','hour', and 'value' (hourly).

I used seaborn boxplot to visualise outliers and hide them (using `showflier = False`, see in the sample code below). Is there a quick way to use the seaborn boxplot properties to replace outliers in all levels (ie. year, month, day, hour)?

The original dataset contains time and value: Y-M-D H:M:S, value.
I converted the time to datetime and added new columns - year, month day, hour.

To remove the outliers based on the box plots at all levels, I could potentially use groupby by the different time intervals, was wondering if I could use the seaborn boxplot properties? Or what might be the best way to do in this case? Since I need to produce those plots as part of my data visualisation.

```
sns.boxplot(x='year', y='Value',data=data,ax=axes[0,0],showfliers=False)
sns.boxplot(x='month',y='Value',data=data,ax=axes[0,1],showfliers=False)
sns.boxplot(x='week', y='Value',data=data,ax=axes[1,0],showfliers=False)
sns.boxplot(x='day', y='Value', data=data,ax=axes[1,1],showfliers=False)
sns.boxplot(x='hour',y='Value',data=data,ax=axes[2,0],showfliers=False)


# The original dataset looks like this 
2017-03-31 15:45:00,10
2017-03-31 16:00:00,23
2017-03-31 16:15:00,45
2017-03-31 16:30:00,5
2017-03-31 16:45:00,46
2017-03-31 17:00:00,7
2017-03-31 17:15:00,3
2017-03-31 17:30:00,86
2017-03-31 17:45:00,51
2017-03-31 18:00:00,75
2017-03-31 18:15:00,74
2017-03-31 18:30:00,09
2017-03-31 18:45:00,79
2017-03-31 19:00:00,72
2017-03-31 19:15:00,80
2017-03-31 19:30:00,5
2017-03-31 19:45:00,45
2017-03-31 20:00:00,7
2017-03-31 20:15:00,7
2017-03-31 20:30:00,73
2017-03-31 20:45:00,88
....

#Converted the above data into the df below

                     Date   Value  year month week day hour
...
17    2013-11-08 06:00:00     75  2013    11   44   5   06
18    2013-11-08 07:00:00     49  2013    11   44   5   07
19    2013-11-08 08:00:00   757.0  2013    11   44   5   08
20    2013-11-08 09:00:00  209.0  2013    11   44   5   09
21    2013-11-08 10:00:00  56.0  2013    11   44   5   10
22    2013-11-08 11:00:00  540.0  2013    11   44   5   11
23    2013-11-08 12:00:00  229.0  2013    11   44   5   12
24    2013-11-08 13:00:00  413.0  2013    11   44   5   13
25    2013-11-08 14:00:00  427.0  2013    11   44   5   14
...
```

Comment: What's your dtypes? Pls, provide an example of your dataset.

Comment: Hi @steven, please see the updated question, right now column 'year' - 'hour' is in string format, I used strftime('%m') to convert '2013-11-08 06:00:00' into '11' (for example for 'month'). However when I use them to filter out the out of hours part I convert them to .astype(int)

Comment: I would say convert them (other than value and data) to str and then just write a for loop

Comment: Thanks @steven, that's a good idea, I will give it a go